# Превышении допустимой нагрузки на сервер, как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

Пришло уведомление от хостинг провайдера о превышении допустимой нагрузки на сервер более 100 процессорных минут на web и mysql сервере . Хостинг adm.tools. Раньше таких предупреждений не получали, провели анализ логов и графиков нагрузок по всех сайтам пики нагрузок наблюдаются на одинаковые числа 5 февраля и 22 февраля. При чем нет разницы сайт работающий, зарегистрирован ли в гугле, на одном даже индексного файла нет.
Читал решение такой проблемы, то находил конкретно для одного сайта: обновления версии php, оптимизация запросов к бд или кеширование, но проблема со всеми. 
Может кто-то встречался с таким или может что-то подсказать по даной проблеме

Comment: Проверьте планировшик. Может что то по графику запускает

Comment: _"одинаковые числа 5 февраля и 22 февраля"_ - что-то я не понял, что тут одинаковое...

Comment: @Qwertiy дни выдачи зарплаты :). Похоже, ТС имеет ввиду, что в эти дни одинаково возросла нагрузка на все сайты.